# Punishment, free will, and being an agent

Tags: reward-punishment, hashgacha-pratit

I seem to recall (in the context of no one experiencing hurt/punishment unless Hashem decreed it) that those who are lacking in merit are used as instruments to punish others, so we pray to not be an agent of someone else's punishment, but I cannot recall a source. To clarify: where/what is the source where we pray not to be an agent of punishment?